# Get View object from a Android composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I need to override a method and return a View inside a Composable function. Is there a way to get View out of another Composable function?

I need something like this where getInfoContents() will return a view just with a Text. The code below will not compile obviously. I can always inflate an XML layout but want to return a View that is generated by a Composable function.

```
    AndroidView({ mapView }) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            val map = mapView.awaitMap()

            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
                override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker): View? {
                    return AndroidView(factory = {
                        Text(text = "Hello")
                    }).toView() ... or something like this
                }

                override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker): View? {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```